# SQL query returning incorrect result to get departments

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, subquery, inner-join

I have a table `Department` like this:

```
DepartmentName    City            NumberOfEmployees    Country
----------------------------------------------------------------
Abc               California      100                  USA
Xyz               Chicago         200                  USA
Lmn               Sydney          300                  Aus
Pqr               Paris           400                  France
```

**Technologies**:

```
TechnologyId    Name     DepartmentName 
----------------------------------------
1               Hadoop     Abc
2               Hadoop     Abc
3               Hadoop     Xyz
4               Hadoop     Lmn
5               Adobe      Pqr
6               Adobe      Lmn
7               Adobe      Abc
```

This is what I am trying to do :

- Get all the departments that have both Hadoop and Adobe

Query:

```
SELECT 
    Department.DepartmentName, Department.DepartmentName, 
    Department.DepartmentName, Department.DepartmentName, 
    Technologies.Name 
FROM 
    Department 
INNER JOIN 
    Technologies ON Department.DepartmentName = Technologies.DepartmentName
WHERE 
    (((Technologies.Name) IN ('Hadoop', 'Adobe')));
```

But this is returning incorrect result.

Can anyone please help me with the query?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: Is there a reason to use the Department table for this question? It seems like the question "Get all the departments that have both Hadoop and Adobe" can be answered with just the Technologies table

Comment: @IceCreamToucan But I want all the fields from Department table that is why

Comment: Just a side note: "California" is **not** a city .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `exists`:

```
select d.*
from department d
where
    exists (
        select 1 
        from technologies t 
        where t.departmentname = d.departmentname and t.name = 'Hadoop'
    )
    and exists (
        select 1 
        from technologies t 
        where t.departmentname = d.departmentname and t.name = 'Adobe'
    )
```

With an index on `technologies(departmentname, name)`, this should be an efficient option.

Comment: Why not use `where d.name = 'Hadoop'` and remove the first `exists`?

Comment: @Scratte: but `name` comes from the `technologies` table not from `department`.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that. I was just about to write the query, I thought you wrote. Change the table name.

Comment: Could you please explain whats the meaning of doing this "select 1" in your query?

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow: this is a typical construct when use `exists`. Since we just want to know if *some record* exists, we discard the actual results with `select 1`.

Comment: How about if we do like  :select * from Technologies from Technologies where t.Name = 'Hadoop' and select t.Name from Technologies where t.Name='Adobe'.

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow: I am unsure what you really mean, but `select ... from ... and select ... from ...` is not valid SQL.

Comment: We will have 1 subquery for checking for Adobe something like that.What do you say. I have seen one my friend writing query like that so I was kind of wondering because that was bit simple I guess

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow: to me, `exists` is the way to go here. But if you come up with another working query, you might want to add an answer to your own question!

Answer (score 1):

try like below using `distinct count`

```
SELECT  Department.DepartmentName, City,NumberOfEmployees,Country
FROM Department  where DepartmentName in (

select DepartmentName  from Technologies
WHERE Name In ('Hadoop','Adobe')
group by DepartmentName
having count( distinct Name)=2
)
```

Comment: Problem is count(distinct Name) is not working in microsoft access

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the department name, then aggregation is simple:

```
select t.departmentname
from technologies t
where t.Name in ('Hadoop', 'Adobe')
group by t.departmentname
having min(t.name) <> max(t.name)
```

You only need the `departments` table if there are additional columns there you want for the result set.

Comment: I think `count(*) > 1` would be better. I don't think `count(*) = 2` will pick up `Abc`

Comment: I want all the department fields so could you update your answer with another version but keep this version of query as well. Thanks :)

Comment: `having count(*) = 2` or `having count(*) > 1` will return incorrect results given that the sample data demonstrates that you can have two records in Technologies with the same Name & Department Name (e.g. ID 1 & 2). If `having count(*) = 2` is used, `Abc` is excluded, and if `having count(*) > 1` is used and ID 7 didn't exist, then `Abc` would be incorrectly included.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff though unfortunately MS Access doesn't support `count(distinct ...)`

Comment: @Learning-Overthinker-Confused . . . Then LeeMac's or GMB's solution is recommended.  I answered only because your question was not clear about the other fields, so this seemed like a simpler alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the DepartmentName, there's no need to use the department table, and this query will work:

```
select distinct t.departmentname
  from technologies t
 where t.name = 'Hadoop'
   and exists (select 1 
                from technologies t2 
               where t.departmentname = t2.departmentname
                 and t2.name = 'Adobe')
```

If you need more from the department table, then go with the answer from @GMB

Answer (score 1):

```
select    d.*
from      Department d
          join Technologies t
            on d.DepartmentName = t.DepartmentName
where     t.Name in ('Hadoop', 'Adobe')
group by  t.DepartmentName   
having    count(distinct t.Name) = 2
```

Output

```
#   DepartmentName       City NumberOfEmployees Country
# 1            Abc California               100     USA
# 2            Lmn     Sydney               300     Aus
```

Here is another option if you cannot use `count(distinct`, but I think it may be less efficient than `exists` as in @GMB's answer

```
select    distinct
          d.*
from      Department d
          join Technologies t_h
            on d.DepartmentName = t_h.DepartmentName
          join Technologies t_a
            on d.DepartmentName = t_a.DepartmentName
where     t_h.Name = 'Hadoop'
          and t_a.Name = 'Adobe'
```

Comment: We have already done group by department name than why you have done count(distinct t.Name) ? count(*)=2 wont do?

Comment: The Technologies table has multiple entries per (Department, Technology) pair in some instances (e.g. Department Abc and Technology Hadoop), so you need to count distinct not just count. Otherwise, you may return departments with 2 entries for the same technology.

Comment: All right but actuall count(distinct t.Name) is not working in Microsoft access.

Comment: I see, did not realize Access doesn't support this. I think GMB's answer seems to be the best option if `count(distinct` is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could join the `Departments` table to an aggregated subquery which uses `min` & `max` to verify that the department contains both of the targeted technologies, e.g.:

```
select d.* from department d inner join
(
    select t.departmentname
    from technologies t
    where t.name in ('Adobe','Hadoop')
    group by t.departmentname
    having min(t.name)='Adobe' and max(t.name)='Hadoop'
) q
on d.departmentname = q.departmentname
```